# Maven execution of test not working

Tags: maven, jenkins, testlink

Hi everybody i'm actually using Jenkins and testlink (with testLink Plugin) to make test automation.

I am not familiar with IC and testlink so i try to take a good start with the "TestLink Plug-in Tutorial".

But when I run a build I am getting following error:

```
[workspace] $ C:\maven-3.0.4\bin\mvn.bat -s C:\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml -gs C:\maven-    3.0.4\conf\settings.xml clean test -DsuiteXmlFiles=suite.xml                                                                     
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Jenkins TestLink Plug-in Tutorial 0.3-SNAPSHOT   
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]             
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jenkins-testlink-plugin-                  tutorial ------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Deleting C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\target
    [INFO]       
    [INFO] --- docbkx-maven-plugin:2.0.11:generate-pdf (book-output) @ jenkins-testlink-plugin-tutorial ---   
    [INFO] Processing input file: book.xml   
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE   
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 23.377s   
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 19 17:43:14 CET 2013  
    [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/112M  
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.agilejava.docbkx:docbkx-maven-plugin:2.0.11:generate-pdf (book-output) on project jenkins-testlink-plugin-tutorial: Failed to read source: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.  
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.  
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:  
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am using a proxy defined in my settings.xml in maven/conf .

I think that maven can't reach the goal test when it is generating the pdf.

I googled a lot but nothing of really usefull, can someone help me plz?

Comment: I would assume that the docbkx is trying to access dtd files etc. from outside (internet) to validate the xml file. Furthermore why are you using such strange command line parameters (just use **mvn clean test**). Furthermore usually you don't need a suite file. The best is to really run **mvn -X ...** and take a deep look into the output.

Comment: Defining things in maven/conf/settings.xml is the wrong location, cause this is part of the maven distribution. It will be overwritten the next time you are updating/changing the maven version. Better location is the ~/.m2/settings.xml file this is also true for running inside a CI solution like jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for this first advice! I don't know what is the use of this commande -DsuiteXmlFiles=suite.xml but no changes without it. With the -X i've got this :

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          com.agilejava.docbkx:docbkx-maven-plugin:2.0.11:generate-pdf (book-output)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <artifacts>${plugin.artifacts}</artifacts>
  <draftMode>no</draftMode>
  <foCustomization>src/main/book/stylesheets/style.xsl</foCustomization>
  <fop1Extensions>1</fop1Extensions>
  <generatedSourceDirectory>C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\target/book/generated/en</generatedSourceDirectory>
  <highlightSource>1</highlightSource>
  <includes default-value="*.xml">book.xml</includes>
  <postProcess>
    <copy todir="C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace/target/book/media">
      <fileset dir="C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace/src/main/book/media/">
        <include name="**/*.css"/>
        <include name="**/*.png"/>
        <include name="**/*.gif"/>
        <include name="**/*.jpg"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </postProcess>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <sourceDirectory>C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace/src/main/book/en/</sourceDirectory>
  <targetDirectory>C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\target/book/en/</targetDirectory>
  <targetFileExtension default-value="fo"/>
  <xincludeSupported>true</xincludeSupported>
</configuration>
```

and this :

```
[DEBUG]   (f) draftMode = no
[DEBUG]   (f) foCustomization = src/main/book/stylesheets/style.xsl
[DEBUG]   (f) fop1Extensions = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourceDirectory = C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\target\book\generated\en
[DEBUG]   (f) highlightSource = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) includes = book.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) postProcess = 
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.tupilabs:jenkins-testlink-plugin-tutorial:0.3-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDirectory = C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\src\main\book\en
[DEBUG]   (f) targetDirectory = C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\target\book\en
[DEBUG]   (f) targetFileExtension = fo
[DEBUG]   (f) xincludeSupported = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Catalogs to load: jar:file:/C:/Users/rlyonnet/.m2/repository/net/sf/docbook/docbook-xsl/1.75.2/docbook-xsl-1.75.2-ns-resources.zip!/docbook/catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Using stylesheet: jar:file:/C:/Users/rlyonnet/.m2/repository/net/sf/docbook/docbook-xsl/1.75.2/docbook-xsl-1.75.2-ns-resources.zip!/docbook/fo/docbook.xsl
[DEBUG] SourceFile: C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\src\main\book\en\book.xml
[DEBUG] TargetFile: C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Plug-in examples\workspace\target\book\en\book.fo
[INFO] Processing input file: book.xml
[DEBUG] Advanced XInclude mode entered
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.450s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 20 09:23:37 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.agilejava.docbkx:docbkx-maven-plugin:2.0.11:generate-pdf (book-output) on project jenkins-testlink-plugin-tutorial: Failed to read source: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```